# How can I get the X value if I know the Y value of a point on a chart?

Tags: c#, charts

if I know the x & y values of 2 points on a chart, and I know the Y value of a position in between those 2 points, how do I get that Y value's corresponding X value?

Basically I would like to get the X position at which that value first occurs, in between the 2 original points.

The Y axis is in doubles, and the X axis uses DateTimes.

It's probable that a data point at exactly the Y value may not exist as an exact point on the chart (it's a line chart) however, but I would need to find the exact X value, not the nearest actual point to it i'm afraid.

Comment: Your question has to do with maths (interpolation), rather than with C# and programming. Just take the two sets of X-Y values surrounding the given Y 90% value and calculate X by relying on the methodology you want (linear regression I presume).

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to get the X value for that Y value though (or the nearest actual X values to the Y value)...

Comment: As said, this is a maths problem. If you have the following x-y values: 8-80 and 10-100 and you want to know what is x for 90 you would have to calculate it via regression (the result here is clearly 9, but in other cases it might be more difficult to know; additionally, there might not be a clearly-defined solution and you might have to rely on an approximation). If you don't know how to do that, do some research; as said: linear regression should work for you. But this question is not on-topic here.

Comment: Right, ignoring my particular problem then, how do I find the X position for a point, in between 2 existing points, where I know its Y value?

Comment: I told you: via linear regression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), but this is not a programming issue.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `LineChart` the calculation is really just simply **interpolation** math.

But it still does take some knowledge about how `Chart` works.

You have normal numbers for the Y-Values but have `DateTimes` for the `X-Values`.

This wouldn't work well with math so we'd expect the need to transform the dates to numbers.

But `Chart` does just that internally, using calls to [`FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ToOADate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The nice thing is that this means that what you add as a `DateTime` value internally is stored as a number, in fact as a `double`.

So you can indeed do the math **straight forward**.  Here is a code example that shows how to find a point on the same line as two given points with a given y-value.

[image]

To make it look nice I add the calculated point as a new `DataPoint` to a **second** series of type `Point`..

First I prepare my chart:

```
chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
chart1.Series.Clear();
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("CA");
Series S1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
Series S2 = chart1.Series.Add("S2");
S1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
S2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
S1.Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2015, 12, 10), 10);
S1.Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2015, 12, 31), 31);

DataPoint dp1 = S1.Points[0];
DataPoint dp2 = S1.Points[1];
```

Now I set the `Y-Value` for which I search the `X-Value`:

```
double y3 = 24;   // X-Mas ;-)
```

Now I calculate the deltas and the slope. This can, of course be done all in one but I spell it out for clarity..:

```
double deltaY = dp2.YValues[0] - dp1.YValues[0];
double deltaX = dp2.XValue - dp1.XValue;
double slope = deltaY / deltaX;
```

Finally I calculate the X-Value you are looking for:

```
double x3 = dp1.XValue + (y3 - dp1.YValues[0]) * slope;
```

Now I can show that the new point indeed sits on the line between the first two points:

```
S2.Points.AddXY(x3, y3);
S2.Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
```