# C# XY Chart, get y value based on x value

Tags: c#, charts, interpolation, extrapolation

I have 2d chart which is consisted from well known points and now I want to get y value for some desired x. I want to call method where I pass x value and method will return y value. Is there any lib which can help me to achieve this?

Here is example
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with 'I have 2d chart which is consisted from well known points' do you have an equation for it? Maybe you should ask this in the math stack.

Comment: Please note that asking for recommendations of libraries etc is off topic here. Depending on the size of the chart simple implementation of searching for the correct position and doing linear interpolation will be easy to implement.

Comment: Asuming MSChart: [Another post about interpolating chart values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285166/how-can-i-get-the-x-value-if-i-know-the-y-value-of-a-point-on-a-chart/34444316#34444316)